# how do i email form submissions through url's

Tags: forms, api, email, url, shopify

I would like to set up a form on my Shopify website. I want the content of the form to be sent to me via email. So I would like to use the `get` method and set the forms `action` attribute to a URL that will send me an email with the submissions. 
The question is, how do I send an email through URL's? Or do I need to use API for this? Is it possible at all? Or is it gonna be possible for me to submit the form to a mystore.myshopify.com page?
I have already tried searching some similar questions, but nothing was satisfying.

Comment: Do not use Shopify Forms and use a tool instead which will send you an email on form completion. There are lot of providers for the same. Search for "shopify form fill app" in google.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an email is something that is done on a back-end of the server. With Shopify it's not possible because you don't have access to the back-end.

But the default Shopify contact form does send you an email when it's submitted, so you can use it. You can modify its fields, copy it to other pages, etc.

If you want more customization options, or more control you'll have to use a service. Shopify recommends Wufoo or Jotform. But you can use whatever you like.

One additional thing. If you have a server somewhere where you can access the back-end, you can send your form data there and email it yourself with PHP or any other language that can run there and send emails.